# Style a polymer element import from external stylesheet

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am using the polymer `paper-card` element from the polymer catalog.

I am able to specify a mixin from within my html file by using:

```
<style is="custom-style">
paper-card {
  width:300px; 
  --paper-card-header:{width:200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  border-radius: 200px;
};
}
</style>
```

How can I specify the same style from an external stylesheet? I do not want to change the contents of `paper-card.html` import file.

Thanks.

Comment: what you mean from an external stylesheet? Example you provided has syntax of external stylesheet. If you are using style inside your element you don't need to use `is="custom-style"` . And if you are using external stylesheet, then you have to import it to your element by `<style include="custom-style">`

Comment: paper-card.html is an element from the polymer catalog. I am importing it into my html file. I also have a `styles.css` which I am importing into my html file. I would like to specify the above block of css in my `styles.css` and have it applied to my polymer element.

Comment: there isn't anything different. The same way you edit css rules in your html element you can also do in external stylesheet that need to be just included then.

Answer (score 1):

To include the styles for a component in an external stylesheet, you can do the following:

- If the stylesheet is a `CSS` file, simply import it as you would any other stylesheet. ***This has been deprecated***
- You can create a stylesheet in the same way that you would create a custom Polymer component:

```
<dom-module id="global-styles">
  <template>
    <style>
      .card {
        // Your styles go here as normal
      }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

You import this into your Polymer component that you wish to apply them to:

```
<link rel="import" href="../path/to/my/external/styles">
<dom-module id="some-other-component">
  <template>
    <style include="global-styles"></style>
      <style>
        //Some more styles
      </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

For more info on this, and specific guidelines / rules, [check out the Polymer Docs on this!](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules)